# zeros and poles of meromorphic section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, multivariable-calculus, complex-geometry

I'm a bit confused regarding the following example: it is stated that
$$ \frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{x^2yz}$$
is a meromorphic section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1)$,
and then one is asked to find poles and zeros.

Passing in a patch where $x \neq 0$ we can multiply by $x$ and write
$$ \frac{1+w_1^3+w_2^3}{w_1w_2}$$
but this doesn't have a limit for $(w_1,w_2) \to (-1,0)$:
how does this fact (if correct) rely with the above?

Comment: The zeros and poles will be curves (divisors), not points. The point you found, [x:y:z] = [1:-1:0], is at the intersection of a divisor of zeros and a divisor of poles (which is why that limit doesn't exist).